# Analytic continuation of $\sin(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-continuation

Why $$\sin{ (z)} =\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$$ the only  analytic function, is equal to $\sin{(x)}$ for $z=x \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Why are you interested in this question and what have you tried so far?

Comment: It's a task, that I found on the internet. I have no idea, how I can argue here. Do you have a hint?

Comment: Try the identity theorem from complex analysis.

Answer (score 2):

**Lemma** Let $f,g$ be two entire functions which are equal on $\mathbb R$. Then, they are equal on $\mathbb C$.

**Proof** Since $f-g$ is analytic and the set of zeroes has an acumulation point, by the identity theorem for analytic functions $f-g=0$.

---

Now apply this Lemma to $f(z)=\sin(z)$ and $g(z)=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$.

Alternatelly, you can argue that any function which is equal to $\sin(z)$ on $\mathbb R$ must be analytic on $\mathbb R$, and hence its Taylor series is the Taylor series of $\sin(z)$. But by Taylor Theorem, any such function must be equal to the Taylor series on $\mathbb C$.

Comment: I have a question to your proof: Why does the set of zeroes have an acumulation point?

Comment: @Leon1998 0 for example is an accumulation point, since it is the limit of $\frac{1}{n} \in \mathbb R$

Comment: Thank you, that means applied for my example:  The set$ f(z_0)=g(z_0)$ with $z_0=0$  has an accumulation point in C. Is that ok?

Comment: @Leon1998 Do you know what an acumulation point is?

Comment: Yes, what's the problem in my proof. Where is the mistake?

Comment: @Leon1998 The set $f(z_0)=g(z_0)$ with $z_0=0$ is a set with a single element... The way you write it means something completely different than what you mean to say.

Comment: I don't get, how I can write this in the right form. I get your argument.

Comment: How would you write it?